# after magento upgrade 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.9 add to cart after blank screen open

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, addtocart, ajax

URL like generate https://domain.com/stage/checkout/cart/add/uenc/
how to solve it this issue 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If blank screen showing then enable error log it will show you the exact error.

Comment: log is available like (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in  app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/ajax/product/view.phtml on line 31

Comment: which extension you are using in foreach empty array coming that's why showing this.

Comment: this issue solved by me.after add to cart any product in cart  but display in Nan form after click cart redirect to shopping cart page and display message like "You have no items in your shopping cart. Click here to continue shopping."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solving a problem by me, the problem is overriding core functionality in a local folder so comment after working perfectly.

so anyone can fetch that type of issue first check the ***log file***, ***third party extension disable*** after check may work...

Thank You...
Happy Codding...